# 2 way binding on RadzenTextBox in a RadzenDataList in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Create an editable list of items with textboxes.
So iv'e used a `RadzenDataList`, bound it to a list of strings.
Then I've used a `RazenTextBox` inside the template:

```
<RadzenDataList Data="@_retrospectiveBoard.WhatWentWell"  TItem="string">
    <Template Context="item">
        <RadzenCard>
            <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="@item"/>
        </RadzenCard>
    </Template>
</RadzenDataList>
```

The `RadzenCard` is just for the looks

However, i get a list of text-boxes, but whenever i change the focus to another text-box the content will reset.
So the 2 way binding is not working as expected.

Is this even possible? Can i 2 way bind to the context of the template, or do i have to intercept the textbox events and update the data in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I reflected over the problem I thought maybe a string won't work, because technically a string can'T be modified, since it is immutable.
So I've wrapped the string into an object that contains a string, and there we go!:

```
<RadzenDataList Data="@_retrospectiveBoard.WhatWentWell"  TItem="RetrospectiveDataItem">
    <Template Context="item">
        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="@item.Text"/>
    </Template>
</RadzenDataList>
```